# AWS SSM IAM Access Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have my users who connect to my AWS EC2 instances via SSM. The instances do not have a public-IP, nor is there a jump-host, and hence there is no way to connect directly.

Each EC2 instance has a name tag, I wish for the IAM policy to be restricted by the tag name. Restricting by instance ID will not be feasible for multiple reasons.

The `NAME` tag on the ec2 server is `client-name`. The **ec2's policy here works fine** to limit access to the instances. I can see that via the console. However, the **SSM policy doesn't seem to work**, I have made 100s of changes to try and make it work. I keep getting the error below. Would appreciate any help.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "client-name"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "client-name"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My user named `testuser_delme2` uses the following command to connect, and the error is as follows:

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-003000333337777c7 --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters portNumber="3389",localPortNumber="3389"
```

**Error:**

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartSession operation: User: arn:aws:iam::222666555000:user/testuser_delme2 is not authorized to perform: ssm:StartSession on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-1::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSession because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:StartSession action
```

Comment: So `"client-name"` is a tag on the session manager? Sorry, your setup is unclear. Where and how do you call `ssm:StartSession`? What tags do you expect to use and where?

Comment: Thanks Marcin. let me update the question & update with your queries.

Comment: If you temporarily remove the tag condition on the `ssm:*` permission, does it work?

Comment: hi John. Yes indeed. If I remove the condition the user gets access to all the EC2 servers (which I dont want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out the issue, and posting it here in case it helps others. For some strange reason **ssm start-session** does not work the same way as other SSM commands.

This is the correct way:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:*","ssm:StartSession"],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/Name": "client-name"}}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["ec2:DeleteTags", "ec2:CreateTags"],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:DescribeInstances", "s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "kms:*"],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "ssm:*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:*"
        },
        {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":["ssm:SendCommand"],
         "Resource":["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"],
         "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/Name": "client-name"}}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you share the reason for the difference?

Comment: we need more details on what you did !

Comment: this would work obviously because you just allowed wide openly ssm:* on all ARNs

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly add policies for specific SSM documents (e.g. StartPortForwardingSession, StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost)

Here is the more fine-grain IAM policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": ["ssm:StartSession"],
         "Resource": [
                // add all of the SSM documents you want to allow. 
                "arn:aws:ssm:*::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
                "arn:aws:ssm:*::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSession"
            ]
        },
        {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":["ssm:SendCommand"],
         "Resource":["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"],
         "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "client-name"
             }
           }
        }
    ]
}
```